# non-english character in read.csv() - R

Tags: r, encoding, read.csv

I'm reading a `.csv` file with encoding `UTF-8`:

```
orden_cat <- read.csv("Input/Orden de categorias.csv", sep=";", encoding="UTF=8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

However, it doesn't read the spanish accents well anyway:

[image]

And also when I try to save the script, it gives me this "error":

[image]

Before all these errors, I copied and pasted the Rproject in a new address (with all the files and sub-carpets. I have related addresses, so what could be the problem?

Comment: I have also worked with spanish accents/ñ/etc. before and have been able to do so using text encoding `ISO8859-1`

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the file is actually encode as UTF-8?? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: If you mean File -> "Save with Encoding" and the UTF-8 option is shaded (as when I use "Reopen with Encoding"), then it is encoded as UTF-8. I don't know how to make a reproducible example for this case, as if I write something in spanish in the console and save it in a variable, it saves it correctly. The problem is just reading the .csv file.

Comment: Are you sure that it's UTF-8? You might be able to find the encoding with `readr::guess_encoding` https://rdrr.io/cran/readr/man/encoding.html Or provide a sample file.

Comment: Thanks ! It's not. It's 100% ASCII. How do I change this encoding if I'm reading with UTF-8 in read.csv()?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was `Orden de categorias.csv` was saved as `.csv with UTF-8 encoding`, and if I save it as just `.csv` it works perfectly.